# Can I migrate S3 to MinIO

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I am finding way to migrate AWS S3 data to MinIO

Datas on AWS-S3 should be moved to MinIO.

There are few ways to migrate data from MinIO to S3, but I can't find way on opposite
will there be any tool or function to duplicate S3 data?

MinIO - S3 api gateways are same so I thought I could duplicate every data with api calls. If I could, I want to know how I can call API.